# Polymer fire parent element

Tags: javascript, polymer, dom-events, polymer-1.0

How do I trigger the parent element on-tap function from its child?

```
<div class="parent-el" item-index="[[index]]" on-tap="openItem">
    <div>[[item.name]]</div>
</div>
```

I have tried creating different function for child to fire the parent.

```
<div on-tap="openItem2">[[item.name]]</div>

openItem2: function(e) {
  var parent = e.target.parentNode;
  this.fire('openItem', parent);
}
// Nothing happens on this
```

or

```
openItem2: function(e) {
  var parent = e.target.parentNode;
  this.openItem(parent);
}
// Outputs error
```

I am still new to Polymer and still gets confused.

Comment: Do you want to get parent element or trigger parent element function?

Comment: trigger parent element function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to get parent and trigger it's function. By default the `event.propagation` goes to parent if you don't stop it using `event.stopPropagation()`. So, just have a parent function.

```
openItem: function(e){
  // write your logic
}
```